# Debugging SQL Queries with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm working with the Spring Framework, and I'm following a test driven development. I'm getting an exception but I'm not entirely sure why so I'd like to see what the query jdbc is actually running. The attempted query is the following:

```
public OrderEntity addOrderEntity(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO ORDERS(ID,REVISION,CONTRACT_ID,PROJECT_ID,WORKSITE_ID,DROPZONE_ID,DESCRIPTION_ID,MANAGER_ID,DELIVERY_DATE,VOLUME) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    String id = (orderEntity.get_id() != null) ? orderEntity.get_id() : UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    jdbcTemplate.update(id,1,orderEntity.getContractNo(),orderEntity.getProjectID(),orderEntity.getWorksiteID(),orderEntity.getDropzoneID(),orderEntity.getDescriptionID(),orderEntity.getManagerID(),orderEntity.getDeliveryDate(),orderEntity.getVolume());

    return getOrderEntityById(id);
}
```

So, what's the best way to see what the query JDBC is running or get some useful information? It currently throws `org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException` (which I find infinitely unhelpful) so I don't really know what could be going wrong.

EDIT: Have now added log4j but still not getting a useful query. Property file is below:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=trace, stdout

log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=DEBUG
```

Comment: And that isn't helpful because? Your Query takes too long to complete. Check if there aren't any locks on your database.

Comment: I've found it throws this no matter what the problem was - foreign key constraint failures caused this as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable tracing of the queries using:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

Especially

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE
```

this will show messages like this:

```
 TRACE StatementCreatorUtils:206 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [TheValueWillBeHere]
```

Comment: Unless I've missed a step, it didn't tell me what the actual query it ran was - it gives something like `INSERT INTO PROJECTS (ID,REVISION,PROJECT_NAME) VALUES(?,?,?)` instead of something like `INSERT INTO PROJECTS (ID,REVISION,PROJECT_NAME) VALUES("proj1",1,"project")`

Comment: (it also didn't help with this actual query, it hasn't even appeared in my log)

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, the log to show params is TRACE.

Comment: Especially for StatementCreatorUtils which will show you the query params